# How to get the reference of a TextBlock.Text property

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, ivalueconverter

Well I am stuck with an issue where I want to get the text that the `TextBlock` has but it's not working. I am stuck with a `System.NullReferenceException`

I have built a calendar where the dates are placed in the `TextBlock` now I want to get this data and compare it to the current date then highlight the date.

Here are the codes I have used:

```
public class DateColorConvertor : IValueConverter
{

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new object();
    }
    public object Convert(object sender, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string currentItem = null;
        currentItem = (sender as TextBlock).Text;
        if (currentItem.Equals(DateTime.Today.Date))
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            else
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Grid Margin="10,102,10,298">
    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Calendar.DateCollection}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="dateGrid"  Background="Black" Width="50" Height="30">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <local:DateColorConvertor x:Key="DateColorConvertor"/>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtDate" Text="{Binding}"  Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DateColorConvertor}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsTapEnabled="True"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, bind to the property and convert the value.

Comment: can help me out more first time using c#

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.

An `IValueConverter` receives the value being bound, and nothing else.

In particular, that parameter is called `value`, not `sender` ([source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Data/IValueConverter.cs,68)).
You should simply cast that value to `DateTime` and consume it directly.

Also, you can return `Brushes.Red`.

Comment: i tried this but i have an error `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`. Maybe i got it wrong im still new to it though

here is the codes:
`public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(value.ToString());

            if (dt.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            else
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }`

Comment: @user3411961: Use the debugger to see what `value` is.

Comment: since the value that is stored in the textblock is not in the format `DateTime` i have changed the codes:

` string dt = value.ToString();

            if (dt.Equals(DateTime.Now.Date))
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            else
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);`

Comment: A string will never equal a date.

Comment: i think the error `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime` was because the dates in the texblock is not saved as `DateTime` but as a string. any way to correct this? i'm lost

Answer (score 0):

Your Convert signature looks different than what `IValueConverter` interface defines.

```
 // Summary:
    //     Provides a way to apply custom logic to a binding.
    public interface IValueConverter
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Converts a value.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   value:
        //     The value produced by the binding source.
        //
        //   targetType:
        //     The type of the binding target property.
        //
        //   parameter:
        //     The converter parameter to use.
        //
        //   culture:
        //     The culture to use in the converter.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A converted value. If the method returns null, the valid null value is used.
        object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Converts a value.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   value:
        //     The value that is produced by the binding target.
        //
        //   targetType:
        //     The type to convert to.
        //
        //   parameter:
        //     The converter parameter to use.
        //
        //   culture:
        //     The culture to use in the converter.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A converted value. If the method returns null, the valid null value is used.
        object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);
```

Convert method should look like this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string currentItem = string.Format("{0}", value);
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(currentItem, out currentDate))
        {
            if (DateTime.Today.Equals(currentDate))
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }

        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
```